# Way to periodically export data from an active web page to a text file or sheet?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, firefox, export-to-csv, screen-scraping

I'm looking for a way to automatically regularly export data from a certain field of a website to a csv or text file from a browser like Chrome or Firefox, I've tried a lot of different extensions that work like a scraper, but everything needs to be done manually, I'd like it to be done on all my selected open tabs automatically every minute for example and I don't want to use any online paid web scraper, I can't use anything like Google Sheets IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXPATH functions because these are websites where I have to be logged in. Thanks in advance for any help

Scraper extensions but they don't work automatically